# What cluster can I user in my case?

Tags: docker, go, kubernetes

I am going to run my golang app on oracle linux 7 server, I am going to use kubernetes using docker containers. What kind of kubernetes cluster can I use? Can you introduce me some short tutorial for deploying my app. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For short introduction I think this blog post is really good. It will tell you basics and what you should know at start https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/an-introduction-to-kubernetes

But if you want to get deeper, start reading:
https://kubernetes.io/

For a start, use minkube, which allow you to run kubernetes locally https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube